# How are 'dynamic' paremeters in symfony resolved?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I was looking through the symfony source files.and I saw this in Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Resources\config\Security.xml:

```
<service id='security.role_hierarchy' ... >
    <argument>%security.role_hierarchy.roles%</arguments>
```

my question is about the `%security.role_hierarchy.roles%` paramater.this is the parameter provided by the user in the app/config/security.*ml under the `role_hierarchy` key. however I don't understand how that will resolve to `'security.role_hierarchy.roles'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout the SecurityExtension and the createRoleHierarchy function.  you'll see it takes the configuration of security.yml and translates it into the parameter you see.